# how to determine if my android device moved forward or backward?

Tags: android

i am developing an app. that if the person who hold the android device walking ahead then a Toast message will say  "Forward" and if he walking for behind
then  a Toast message will say  "Reverse".

So can any one give me a solution for this problem ?

any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: search for `Accelerometer`

Comment: i am sorry to tell you that Accelerometer didn't solve the problem since it give you the slope not the direction . so if you've another answer i'll be happy

Thank's >>>>